# How to insert in a table with linking column in Kdb+?

Tags: database, time-series, kdb

I created 2 table as below:

```
t1:([] c1:`sym?`c`b`a; c2: 10 20 30)
t2:([] c3:`sym?`a`b`a`c; c4: 1 2 3 4.)
update t1link:`t1!t1.c1?c3 from `t2
sym,:`x
```

I can insert into t1:

```
`t1 insert (`x, 22)
```

But I found this when insert into t2:

```
val: t1.c1?`x
`t2 insert (`x, 22.1, val)  //  report: `t1
`t2 insert (`x, 22.1, `t1!val)  // succceed!
```

My questions is, Why this insertion failed for the first try ? I checked `meta` and the column is type `j`, while `t1linkValue` is typed -7h.

Ps. How to make Kdb+ report more detail about the faied statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `type each flip` or `.Q.s1` you can further inspect the underlying table object.

https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#s1-string-representation

`meta` summarizes which means not all detail is included.

```
q)meta t2
c     | t f  a
------| ------
c3    | s
c4    | f
t1link| j t1
q)type each flip t2
c3    | 20
c4    | 9
t1link| 20
q).Q.s1 t2
"+`c3`c4`t1link!(`sym$`a`b`a`c;1 2 3 4f;`t1!2 1 2 0)"
```

Testing to append to specific columns lists using `,` helps us see where the issue lies:

```
q)(`t1!2 1 2 0),0 #The ! link does not append correctly unless the right hand side is also a link
`t1!2
`t1!1
`t1!2
`t1!0
0
q)(`t1!2 1 2 0),`t1!0
`t1!2 1 2 0 0
q)(`sym$`a`b`a`c),`x #The $ enumeration does allow you to append
`a`b`a`c`x
```

Generally  `` `sym$ `` symbol enumerations and linked columns `` `t1! `` are not really used in memory. Instead they are applied only as the table is being stored to disk in a batch operation.

In memory symbols are automatically interned into memory so there is no speed/memory benefit to manually creating an enumeration.
See: [Is symbol type compressed or indexed in Kdb+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76503087/is-symbol-type-compressed-or-indexed-in-kdb)

In memory, keyed tables are used more often than linked-tables. They are easier to use for this use-case.

When you get in to writing complex layered functions you will be able to use the debugging functionality in the language:

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/debug/

For questions like use information on what are accepted parameters to operators as documented on https://code.kx.com/q/
Along with tools like `.Q.s1` you can break down the operation to get to the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but still another question: I saw `t1link` is typed `20` using `type each flip`, but I saw  \`t1!2   typed `-20h`. So it is supposed to insert a `-20h` var into `20` column?

Comment: You can insert a single item type `-20h` or a list of items `20h`. `0h` is the type for a general list. Negative for atoms of basic datatypes.
Positive for everything else. https://code.kx.com/q/ref/type/